# VSCode how to open a local folder within a local docker container.....without devcontainers.json?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers, vscode-devcontainer

I want start a docker container that I have created, and then mount a local folder to it in a way that doesn't make use of a devcontainers.json file. This is because I would like to test the same local repo out with multiple docker containers and editing the devcontainers.json file is a pain because I have to edit every time I want to change the docker image - where really I just want to do something like:

1. Dev Containers: Open Local Folder in Container
2. Choose Local Folder
3. Choose a docker container that is already running

The problem is that in step 3 I only see options to choose from pre-made base images i.e. Ubuntu 22.04. I can't see anywhere in the list any of my docker containers that I am running. Have I missed any functionality? Does what I'm asking exist......or must I use a devcontainers.json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood your issue:

Once you install Microsoft's Docker extension from the VS Code extensions' tab (`ctrl + shift + x`), you'll be able to do that.
[image: Microsoft's Docker Extension]

This extensions have a "CONTAINERS" tab, where you can open another VSCode window inside a selected container's directory or attach a terminal to the container and manage the system.
[image: Docker extension's containers' tab]

Just right-click on the desired container and you'll see the options.